# Image post to facebook page using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the code.

```
try {
    $post_param = array();                    
    $post_param['message'] =  'Test'; 
    $post_param['object_attachment'] = '94592782743592734' ;
    $response = $fb->post('/'.$page->page_id.'/feed/', $post_param, $page->page_access_token);
 }
 catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
     exit;
 } 
 catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
     echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
     exit;
 }
```

When I try this code, I am getting the error.

Graph returned an error: (#100) Invalid object_attachment parameter

Before that, I have tried to upload photo to itself page and in user photos. And i tried with both facebook picture id. But getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The ID provided in `object_attachment` is invalid; can you check that? How have you retrieved that ID?

Comment: this was fake object id.  Though I have got sorted the issue solved. 
The issue was that, i was using user access token to upload image to page, that's why it was not allowing the image to attach in post.